# Sort with custom function giving reversed results

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the following array (here shown as JSON):

```
[{
    "value": -1,
    "absolute": false,
    "callTime": 0
}, {
    "value": 23,
    "absolute": true,
    "callTime": 1365179295887
}, {
    "value": 1,
    "absolute": false,
    "callTime": 0
}, {
    "value": 1,
    "absolute": true,
    "callTime": 0
}]
```

I need to sort this array by putting the objects with the highest values of the `callTime` property at the top of the array.

I use the following code (based on the explanation of the subject [offered by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description)):

```
var handlers = JSON.parse("[...]");

handlers.sort(function(firstHandler, secondHandler) {
    if (firstHandler.callTime < secondHandler.callTime) {
        return -1; // sort firstHandler to a lower index than secondHandler.
    } else {
        return 1; // sort secondHandler to a lower index than firstHandler.
    }

    return 0;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(handlers));
```

After running the function, I get the following output:

```
[{
    "value": 1,
    "absolute": true,
    "callTime": 0
}, {
    "value": 1,
    "absolute": false,
    "callTime": 0
}, {
    "value": -1,
    "absolute": false,
    "callTime": 0
}, {
    "value": 94,
    "absolute": true,
    "callTime": 1365179553381
}]
```

Which seems to be the inverse of what I'm expecting (notice how the only object with `callTime` different than zero is at the bottom).

I think there I might be missing something big here, or maybe I'm just misled, but also changing the body of the function to:

```
return firstHandler.callTime - secondHandler.callTime
```

should give the correct results, yet it doesn't seem to.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sort function is incorrect. The logic is reversed, because your sort function is indicating that elements with *smaller* values of `callTime` come first, whereas you want larger values to be at the top of the array. Also, you always return -1 or 1, and never 0. It should return 0 when the elements are tied.

Rewrite it as follows:

```
handlers.sort(function(firstHandler, secondHandler) {
    if (firstHandler.callTime > secondHandler.callTime) {
        return -1; // sort firstHandler to a LOWER index than secondHandler.
    } else if (firstHandler.callTime < secondHandler.callTime) {
        return 1; // sort secondHandler to a LOWER index than firstHandler.
    }

    return 0; // sort firstHandler and secondHandler as equal
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I somehow managed to get confused by the JSON representation of the data because I accidentally thought as "lower" as "lower down in the JSON representation" rather than "at a lower index".